# How do I vertically align mulitple images with different heights using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, image, function, dynamic

I have created a script that slides images.  Each image is contained in a "slide" div.  What I want to do is vertically align each individual image using jquery.  Currently am I using:

```
$('.slide img').each(function() {
    var image_height = $(this).height();
    var height_margin = (image_height/2)*-1;
    $('.slide img').css('margin-top', height_margin);
    $('.slide img').css('top', 50%);    
    $('.slide img').css('height', image_height);    

});
```

What I've noticed is that it applies the first height and margin from the first image to ALL of the `<div class"slide"></div>` tags.  Also: `<div class"slide"></div>` has the constant height of 600px.

Not every image is the same and I want it to be dynamic... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `$('.slide img')` inside the `.each` loop, because this selector will change all styles. Currently, you're applying the settings of the last image to all images. Another error in your code: You have forgotten to quote `50%`.

```
$('.slide img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var image_height = $this.height();
    var height_margin = (image_height/2)*-1;
    $this.css('margin-top', height_margin);
    $this.css('top', '50%');    
    $this.css('height', image_height);    
});
```

Your code can be optimized even more:

```
$('.slide img').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var image_height = $this.height();
    var height_margin = -image_height / 2
    $this.css({'margin-top', height_margin,
               'top', '50%',  
               'height', image_height
              });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `.slide` container has a constant height you could apply `display:block` and `margin:auto 0;` to `.slide img` in CSS to achieve the same effect...no JS calculations required.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have a solution, first make the containing DIV's `line-height` matches the height of your tallest image, then use `vertical-align:middle` in a class which you apply to all images, make sure the images are set to `display:inline` though or it wont work.

```
div.container {line-height:300px;} /*or whatever that may be, then*/
img.slides {vertical-align:middle;}
```